# Streaming MP4 in Express, NodeJS (HTTP 206 Partial Content)

Tags: node.js, express, stream

i am trying to stream video from URL via NodeJs express web server.

I am able to stream video, but it is not chunked (`HTTP code 200`). That means, if someone tries to seek (for example to end), they will have to download all the video.

I am using `got` and `express`, but it does not matter, which libraries I will use.

```
const got = require('got');
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const url = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4'

app.get('/stream', async (req, res) => {
  got.stream(url).pipe(res)
})
```

I have learned, that I could use `req.headers.range` to get current position, but returning `HTTP code 206 - partial content` is not possible.

How is the easiest way to achieve this behavior? (In HTML the output will be `<video src="SERVER_URL/stream"></video>`)